# How to convert wide string to normal string?

Tags: excel

This is the first time I encountered this case,

I have read about unicode, ascii but actually it was too difficult for me because I could not distinguish them. My problem is:

I have a text like that in cell O2, when I type in the textbox (in combination with the textbox_change event) I cannot search for O2, after a while debug when i paste text from textbox to O3, now I see they are different but don't know why!

How can i switch from O3 to O2? Please clarify this problem help me!

Thanks you.

[image]

Edit: when I compare the letters at position 2:

```
1. tấn
2. tấn
```

[image]

Comment: Not much to go on. Have you checked for a trailing space?

Comment: Hi, sure! , there are no spaces in both O2 and O3.

Comment: You could use `MID` and compare `O2` to `O3` character by character to help narrow down what the difference is.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, I did what you said and updated the post. I typed them myself in both excel and textbox, however the characters in the textbox changed and I couldn't search O2 value.